# Using the linux 'file' command to determine type (ie. image, audio, or video)

Tags: bash, shell, file-type

The word `file` here refers to the shell [file](http://linux.die.net/man/1/file) command, and not actual files. I want to determine whether a file is a, for example, video file (`.mpg`, `.mkv`, `.avi`). `file` is pretty good at returning `image` for image files, `video` for video files, and `audio` for audio files (and `application/x-empty` for some reason for text). My question is how reliable this is for identifying types. If I did a simple

```
file -ib deliverance.avi | grep video
```

would that work for all of the **main** video files outlined [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_formats#Video)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The results from `file` are less than perfect, and it has more problems with some types of files than others. File basically just looks for particular pieces of binary data in predictable patterns to figure out filetypes.

Unfortunately, in particular, some of the filetypes often used for video fall into this "problematic" category. The newer container formats like `.mp4` and `.mkv` usually have several different MIME types that should properly depend on what type of data is being contained. For example, an `.mp4` could properly be identified as `video/mp4`, `audio/mp4`, or  `application/mp4` depending on the content.

In practice, `file` often makes guesses that simply conform with common usage, and it may work perfectly well for you. For example, while I mentioned some theoretical difficulties with identifying Matroska files correctly, `file` basically just assumes that any Matroska file is a video.  On the other hand, the usage of the Ogg container is more evenly split between audio and video, and I believe the current version of `file` just splits the difference, and identifies Ogg files as `application/ogg`, which wouldn't fall into any of your categories.

The one thing I can say with certainty is that you want the most up-to-date version of `file` you can get your hands on.  The "magic" files that contain the patterns to match against and the MIME types that will result from a match are updated fairly often to include newer filetypes like WebM, or just to improve accuracy for older types.

Comment: Can you provide some advice/links for how to make this more accurate? Off the top of my head, maybe checking the file extension, using [PHP functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php). Surely sites like youtube deal with this same problem. Thanks

Comment: I don't mean to sound negative. `file` is probably about as good as you're going to get. You could also check against the extension if you want to be sure some extensions are detected a certain way (or to counteract a problem you hit in practice).

Comment: I did a preliminary test and file was pretty accurate. Of course it's not going to be easy to get a reliable sample of say 25,000 different video files.

Comment: Do you know how the big sites deal with this issue? Maybe get mplayer to try to play it.

Comment: This is incorrect.  The file command does not look at "particular pieces of binary data in predictable patterns to figure out filetypes."  It looks at the first few characters of the file, which, in unix-land determines a files type.  It is also called the files magic number.  The magic number table then is looked up in a table. frankc's answer below is the correct answer

Comment: The current format of the magic file you'll find basically everywhere allows for patterns significantly more complicated than just "the first few characters of the file" including patterns at static or variable offsets, and can express multi-level tests that more accurately determine a file's type. (Also, I would describe the typical "magic number" as a particular piece of binary data in a predictable pattern, anyway.)

Answer (score 1):

file works by referencing the header of the file against a "magic number" file.  I suspect the best way to see how robust file is to check your local magic number file (possibly /usr/share/magic but see man file for details) for the file types from your referenced list.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it should work for most video/audio/image files. But, if it doesn't, there's actually a file that contains the relations between an extension and it's type:

> The information identifying these files is read from the compiled magic file /usr/share/magic.mgc , or /usr/share/magic if the compile file does not exist.

see:
http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_file.htm

Hope this helps!